# WPF tabControl re-order tabs

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to reorder WPF tab control in using C#

Comment: I believe your best answer is already here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093571/reorder-tabs-in-wpf-tabcontrol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TabControl` has an `ItemsCollection` that it inherits from `ItemsControl`. You can remove items from that list and re-add them using `Add()` and `Remove()` or `RemoveAt()`:

```
Object tabToMove = Items[3];
Items.RemoveAt(3);
Items.Insert(1, tabToMove);
```