# Check if a window is over another window

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am making a webbrowser and I have to make the tabs draggable. So when you pull out a tab, I delete the tabitem from the tabcontrol and put it in another window, which I create on that very moment, and that's the tab, the window, you drag. Now I have to be able to drop the tab back in so I need to check if the window, the window I am dragging, is over another window where it could be dropped.
So I actually need two things:
 1) Is the window over another one?
 2) If it is over a window, is it the first window underneath the window youre dragging?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this should help you with reorder `TabControl`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093571/reorder-tabs-in-wpf-tabcontrol

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good starting point [Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx)

Comment: I know how to drag and drop, but drag and drop doesn't have support for showing actual controls while dragging